# NodeJs GUI frontend

Tags: node.js, user-interface, frontend

I have a nodejs application and I want to create a cool GUI from it. What are some of the  frameworks available out there which are easy to use. I looked at expressjs but was wondering if there are any other cool GUI frameworks for nodejs which simplify front end development.

Comment: GUI is very ambiguous here. You can use AngularJS to create a browser based user interface. Or node-webkit to create a desktop GUI.

Comment: There are several directions you can go: use a traditional toolkit like GTK (see https://github.com/zcbenz/node-gui/ ), use a web browser as the front-end (see http://electron.atom.io/ ), or use something like [blessed](https://github.com/chjj/blessed) to make a console application with a richer interface than just standard I/O as described in James D's answer below.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do and what you mean by front-end. Do you want to control your app from a web browser? Do you want a desktop or mobile app? Is your application already a server or just a command? Lots of missing information here. Express is ultimately not a front-end framework, rather it makes writing http servers easier which is why you see a lot of people use express for their nodejs app (not necessarily front-end)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to create a GUI to start,stop,restart etc.. your nodejs app.

I haven't used any of these yet but I found your question whilst searching and am sharing my findings so far.

Good article here about nodejs TUI

```
http://blog.nodejitsu.com/a-blessed-ui-for-jitsu/
```

Library that can create a nice looking TUI

```
https://github.com/chjj/jitsu-ui
```

Another TUI lib.

```
https://github.com/jocafa/node-term-ui
```

As for GUI node-webkit would be the way I imagine, but im not sure how you would hijack the spawned console windows to prettify the console info and display it in your GUI instead of the console.

**Update**

Supervizer, a process manager with REST api as well.

```
https://github.com/oOthkOo/supervizer
```

Comment: Isn't `jitui-ui` a TUI built with `blessed` for interacting with the [nodejitsu PaaS](https://www.nodejitsu.com/)? I think [blessed](https://github.com/chjj/blessed) is what you want (though they both appear to be written by the same author)

Answer (score 0):

Some popular front-end JavaScript/Typescript frameworks are (in no particular order):

- Angular
- React Native *(React)*
- Vue.js
- Express *(expressjs)*